# Extracting data from Web

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, collect

One really newbie question. 
I'm working on a small python script for my home use, that will collect data of a specific air ticket.

I want to extract the data from skyscanner (using BeautifulSoap and urllib). Example:

http://www.skyscanner.net/flights/lond/rome/120922/120929/airfares-from-london-to-rome-in-september-2012.html

And I'm interested in all the data that are stored in this kind of element, specially the price: http://shrani.si/f/1w/An/1caIzEzT/capture.png

Because they are not located in the HTML, can I extract them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8047666/how-to-combine-scrapy-and-htmlunit-to-crawl-urls-with-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360817/is-there-any-python-module-that-helps-to-crawl-data-from-dom-loaded-by-javascrip , so bottom line is use [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem is that these values are rendered through a javascript code which your browser runs and `urllib`  doesn't - You should use a library that can execute javascript code.

I just googled `crawler python javascript` and I got the some stackoverflow questions and answers which recommends the use of [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [webkit](http://www.webkit.org/). You can use those libraries through [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/). Here are two snippets:

[Rendered/interactive javascript with gtk/webkit/jswebkit](http://snipplr.com/view/66996/renderedinteractive-javascript-with-gtkwebkitjswebkit/)

[Rendered Javascript Crawler With Scrapy and Selenium RC](http://snipplr.com/view/66998/rendered-javascript-crawler-with-scrapy-and-selenium-rc/)

Comment: I checked some other forums and found a solution (using Webkit and QT) that is more sutable for my knowledge level. If somebody is interested:

http://pastebin.com/kWWxj6g6

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on this same exact issue. I have been introduced to Beautifulsoup and later since learned about Scrapy. Beautifulsoup is very easy to use, especially if you're new at this. Scrapy apparently has more "features", but I believe you can accomplish your needs with Beautifulsoup.

I had the same issues about not being able to gain access to a website that loaded information through Javascript and thankfully Selenium was the savior.

A great introduction to Selenium can be found [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html).

Install: `pip install selenium`

Below is a simple class I put together. You can save it as a .py file and import it into your project. If you call the method `retrieve_source_code(self, domain)` and send the hyperlink that you are trying to parse it will return the source code of the fully loaded page when you can then put into Beautifulsoup and find the information you're looking for!

Ex:

```
airfare_url = 'http://www.skyscanner.net/flights/lond/rome/120922/120929/airfares-from-london-to-rome-in-september-2012.html'

soup = BeautifulSoup(SeleniumWebScraper.retrieve_source_code(airfare_url))
```

Now you can parse `soup` like you normally would with Beautifulsoup.

I hope that helps you!

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

class SeleniumWebScraper():

    def __init__(self):
        self.source_code = ''
        self.is_page_loaded = 0
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.is_browser_closed = 0
        # To ensure the page has fully loaded we will 'implicitly' wait 
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)  # Seconds

    def close(self):
        self.driver.close()
        self.clear_source_code()
        self.is_page_loaded = 0
        self.is_browser_closed = 1

    def clear_source_code(self):
        self.source_code = ''
        self.is_page_loaded = 0

    def retrieve_source_code(self, domain):
        if self.is_browser_closed:
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        # The driver.get method will navigate to a page given by the URL.
        #  WebDriver will wait until the page has fully loaded (that is, the "onload" event has fired)
        #  before returning control to your test or script.
        # It's worth nothing that if your page uses a lot of AJAX on load then
        #  WebDriver may not know when it has completely loaded.
        self.driver.get(domain)

        self.is_page_loaded = 1
        self.source_code = self.driver.page_source
        return self.source_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need BeautifulSoup to extract data.

Just do this and your response is converted to a Dictionary which is very easy to  handle.

text = json.loads("You text of the main response content")

You can now print any key value pair from the dictionary.
Give it a try. It is super easy.