# How to use webkit with scrapy

Tags: python, webkit, scrapy

I need to scrape a webpage with javascript and looks like this is resolved in the example at http://snipplr.com/view/66996/renderedinteractive-javascript-with-gtkwebkitjswebkit/
referred in question [Extracting data from Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332847/extracting-data-from-web?lq=1,the) code uses webkit downloader class. I understand that I need to invoke process_request function. What do I pass in as parameter in request. I looked through scrapy documentation to see if I have to pass request object created in scrapy but that does not work.

Also, I understand that the spider object is to be passed in process_request as the last parameter. Which object should that be? Sorry I am new to python, scrapy and webkit so maybe asking questins with obvious answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't "invoke" `process_request` manually, you only have to declare it, the engine will invoke it with all the right parameters.  Just create a file called `middleware.py` (or whatever you want to call it) and type in:

```
...
class WebkitDownloader( object ):
    def process_request( self, request, spider ):
        if not isinstance(request, FormRequest):
            webview = webkit.WebView()
            ...
```

and all the rest of it, and then in your settings.py file type in:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'mybot.middleware.WebkitDownloader': 1000,
    ...
}
```

That should get your middleware working.